# Разделение полномочий: для разных групп скрыть то или иное поле при записи

Tags: yii

В Yii новичок (не ругать). Есть пользователи. Разные группы (всего 6 групп для пользователй).
Вопрос: как для разных групп скрыть то или иное поле при записи. 
Пример:  группа "Продавцы" могут редактировать только поле "наименование товара",
другая группа может редактировать (допустим категорию этого товара) и т.д

Можно, пожалуйста, пример кода. Всем заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Вижу, что нужно юзать Access Control и не сложным механизмом выбирать сценарий изминения модели и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

читаем [RBAC Авторизация в YII и LDAP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/177873/)  - если не понятно, читаем еще раз))) Это на мой взгляд (и не только) лучшая статья про контроль доступа.
А для вашей ситуации я бы заюзал задачи. Что такой здачи там тоже написано

Comment: [Вот](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/22/gibkaia-nastroika-razreshenii-dlia-rolei-rbac) еще неплохая статья по теме.